# Showing full catalog on homepage

Tags: catalog, home

I've been googling well over 2 hours now and for some reason I cannot find a way to add a full catalog to the homepage. I need this cause I want an infinite scroll on the homepage, I'll be able to resolve this.

How can I add a normal product list on the homepage with all items? Preferably sorted by date add (DESC) but that'd be something I should be able to resolve.

I have an extra template file added to the homepage, should I just go ahead and copy the catalog html in here?

Please advise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253389/magento-how-to-display-all-products-in-the-homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the homepage in the CMS -> Manage pages and add the following code snippet into the WYSIWYG

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

This should then list all of the products in your shop on that page.

You could also use the same code to drill down into a specific category, by adding the category variable, e.g.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="9" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253389/magento-how-to-display-all-products-in-the-homepage

Comment: Yeah that worked, but I really had to fiddle around a lot with cache and such, Magento can be so confusing sometimes.